# Create-React-App requires Node 4.0 or higher - on Windows

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I installed NodeJs LTS v8.11.3 for windows.
Then in cmd I wrote **npm -g install create-react-app** but I gave a an error that I need Node 4 or higher.

When I run **node --v**, I have got 0.12.2.

I didn't find how can I change it on windows. I already tried uninstall and restart computer, clean the cache, check windows path if nodeJs is here...

After that, still the same error:

```
*You are running Node 0.12.2.
Create React App requires Node 4 or higher.
Please update your version of Node.*
```

What should I do more? Thanks for ideas.

Comment: Go to Environment Variables dialog (Win+R, `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables` hit Enter). Check your `PATH` variable and look where the node path is pointing to. Change that path to your newer node location.

Comment: Actual path is in Program Files under nodeJs folder. What do you mean by 'newer node location'? In that folder I can not see any files with versions.

Comment: I'm talking about the PATH environment variable which lists where your node bin is located, just follow those instructions and check it

Comment: Yes, I know - that's what I wrote. In PATH enviroment variable is path pointing to C:/ProgramFiles/nodeJs/.

Comment: In that folder right click on node.exe and click Properties and then Details tab and check the version @Thomas

Comment: There were 8.11.3. Exactly that version which I instaled. Actully, I solved it right now. After instalation there were still some files in ProgramFiles. It's weird for me. So I deleted them and instal nodeJs again. I have described the steps that helped me below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it by these steps:

1. Clean cache from cmd.
2. Uninstall nodeJs from Program and Features.
3. Remove folder nodeJs from **PATH variable**.
4. Remove nondeleted folder nodeJs from ProgramFiles (here still were some files(**?!**)).
5. Restart Computer and after that install nodeJs from website.
6. After instalation - Restart Computer again.
7. Run cmd and checked by **node -version**.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I have moved from 0.8 to 0.10, using the .msi package, overwriting the one installed on my system. Package problems were all fixed with npm update -g. Worked like a charm.

In case it does not work like a charm:

npm cache clean usually fixes the problem. Once the cache is empty, just run npm update -g again.

Comment: Why would you be using such antiquated versions of Node? `cache clean` doesn't even exist in modern NPM it's `cache verfy`. But this is not an issue related to NPM anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing happend. Still same problem.