# Error with npx create-react-app in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

I have an issue trying to run npx create-react-app, this is the output:

> You are running Node 8.10.0.
> Create React App requires Node 10 or higher.
> Please update your version of Node.

I tried to install and uninstall nodejs, the version that I have is v8.10.0, that's what I got running sudo apt install nodejs

Am I missing something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51704384/create-react-app-requires-node-4-0-or-higher-on-windows

Solution to the almost same issue here

Comment: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Answer (score -1):

You can update your node version using `npm` which gets installed with NodeJS.

first clear the `npm` cache:

```
npm cache clean -f
```

then Install `n`, Node’s version manager:

```
npm install -g n
```

and at last, use: `n [version.number]` or `n stable` in your CLI.